# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Gardening & Landscaping has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the newly *elected* moderators are... the same ones you've had as your pro-tem mods!:

[image: Stephie]

[image: kevinskio]

[image: Niall C.]

Please thank them for re-committing to Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange! Thanks also to the other candidates for volunteering to support this site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4578708930166784).

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for voting in the election.  I and the rest of the moderators will do our best to see that you, G & L users, have a great place to get answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations everyone!

Thanks to everyone who voted and to all who ran for a moderator position.

May Stephanie, Kevin and Niall have a very fruitful moderation experience within the community.

Good Luck and keep sowing those seeds of patience!